# What is the appropriate way to hide icons from screen readers

Tags: html, accessibility, font-face, wai-aria, screen-readers

In my web application, I have made myself a font that consists solely of icons. I use these icons to complement titles and sub titles within the application and make it more visually appealing.

However, screen readers like JAWS read this out and it makes for an unpleasant experience for users of screen readers.

For instance the character `c` displays an image of a cloud. I use it in this way to complement for instance a header such as `<h1>`:

`<span class="my-font">c</span>`

Now I would like for screen readers to completely ignore this as this is just complementing an existing title and not adding any new meaning to what's on the page. Through my research I have found two possibilities:

`aria-hidden="true"` or `role="presentation"`

I'm just not sure which one of these (or perhaps both) are suitable to what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the [`aria-hidden="true"`](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-hidden) attribute, which says:

> Indicates that the element and all of its descendants are not visible or perceivable to any user as implemented by the author.

This means that the element is not supposed to be perceived by any user. So use:

```
<span class="my-font" aria-hidden="true">c</span>
```

If the icon is supposed to be a link or is not just for decoration, I suggest you have some text accompanying them so that screen readers knows what it is. You can move the text off screen so that it is only visible to screen readers.

**HTML**

```
<span>
    <span class="my-font" aria-hidden="true">c</span>
    <span class="screen-reader">About me</span>
</span>
```

**CSS**

```
.screen-reader {
    position:absolute;
    top:-9999px;
    left:-9999px;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If it's just a decorative icon, it should better be served with CSS instead of HTML, for example with a pseudo-element: `::after(content:…; font:…;)`. Unfortunately, some screenreaders might read this content, too, and we can't apply WAI-ARIA in CSS, of course. So, depending on your situation, you might be "forced" to use markup with `aria-hidden="true"` instead.

If possible, you should also use a corresponding Unicode symbol (like `☁`, which is "U+2601 CLOUD") instead of a irrelevant character (like `c`).

If there is no corresponding character, you should make use of Unicode's [Private Use Areas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Area), which are code points that are left undefined, so you can define your own characters/symbols.

You might be interested in these posts:

- css-tricks.com: [HTML for Icon Font Usage](http://css-tricks.com/html-for-icon-font-usage/)
- nimbupani.com: [Markup-free icon fonts using unicode-range](http://nimbupani.com/markup-free-icon-fonts-with-unicode-range.html)

Answer (score 1):

While `aria-hidden="true"` works to hide the audible icon, it will still show up in the assistive technology's list of links and headings.

I'm still trying to find a way to hide them entirely, but it's tricky. To the OP, yes, `aria-hidden="true"` will hide them somewhat, but not entirely. Don't rely on it alone. Also, make sure you test with real users!

I came across this really good article: http://pictos.cc/articles/using-icon-fonts/

Comment: Clrux, my [answer on another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921724/aria-landmark-role-with-aria-hidden-set-to-true/15930936#15930936) may help you some

Comment: Thanks. You are right. However, I think the two situations are a little different. In my setup, I actually want the screen readers to see empty `<span>`'s, so the extra, superfluous stuff isn't read which can be confusing.

I've since learned that you can use encoded entities which will be interpreted as characters, but won't be seen by assistive tech. A friend pointed me to icomoon.io which helped with my issue.

Thanks for the followup!

Comment: by empty spans, I assume you mean `<span></span>`? They won't see that unless they are navigating by character or word if I am not mistaken. That being said, the only thing that would be announced is "space" or "non-breaking space." But they would need need to know to look for the content. If it is empty, aka null, how do they know to look?

Comment: I had `<span class="icon">help</span> help` which would've turned into a ? once the font was rendered. But, screen readers would read "help help", so I was hoping to hide that first one.

I learned that you can use any icon font so long as you stick within the PUA realm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_(Unicode)). For example, instead of using a word, I'd use U+E000. Those aren't read by screen readers.

I also discovered the CSS attribute `speak: none` which works on modern browsers.