# ARIA landmark role with aria-hidden set to true

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria

ARIA landmark role with aria-hidden set to true are also shown when user lists out the landmarks regions. ( While using JAWS: <kbd>Jaws key</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd>)

Example:

```
<div role="region" aria-label="tools menu" aria-hidden="true">....</div>
```

Which is displayed only on a click of a button "Tools menu"

My question is,

1. Is there a way such that this is not displayed when user lists out landmark roles?
2. Jaws didn't announce that particular region is hidden when I got into that using landmark role. What could have gone wrong? i am using Jaws 12.0
3. Is it working as expected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am confused at what you are trying to do here. An [ARIA Landmark](http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_ARIA_landmarks_to_identify_regions_of_a_page#Description), allows a person using assistive technology to jump to certain parts of a page, so they don't need to read through the page to find a specific area. For example a sidebar, you could add `role="complementary"`, or use the HTML5 `<aside>` tag. [More information on HTML5 & roles at PGB](http://blog.paciellogroup.com/2013/02/using-wai-aria-landmarks-2013/).

The `aria-hidden` attribute is slightly counter-intuitve. So if we have:

```
<p aria-hidden="true">My cool text</p>
```

in code. The browser will render:

> My cool text

If we look at this same block of text with assistive technology, the result would be like having

```
 <p></p>
```

Since you are combining a landmark and an attribute, JAWS is unsure what to do. Since landmarks have more power/authority/whatever, and you say give me all the landmarks, it will see it, and allow you to navigate there. However, once you're *in* it, it will see `<div></div>`.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I was trying to hide few content from the screen reader when they were not ready to be shown and I was doing it wrong. Your suggestion helped me to solve it.

Comment: Hi Ryan, I am facing a problem hiding region roles which are inside a container which is not displayed.To explain I have created a sample below   
    `<div aria-hidden="true" style="display:none;">
      <div role="region" aria-label="region1">Region1</div>
      <div role="region" aria-label="region2">Region2</div>
      <div role="region" aria-label="region3">Region3</div>
    </div>`   

I need to hide region landmarks from the screen reader without having a DOM structure change

Comment: My only guess would be you need to add/remove things via AJAX. I would recomend making a new question because it looks like you are approaching it wrong